# Integrals of the form $\int \log(2+2\cos x)^ndx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, riemann-zeta

$\log$ will be the natural logarithm and $\zeta$ the Riemann zeta function. I'm interested in the following family of integrals:
$$
I_n = \int_0^\pi(\log(2+2\cos x))^n\mathrm{d}x
$$
Some of the values are:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 n& \text{$I_n$}\\ \hline
1 & 0 \\ \hline
2 & 2\pi\zeta(2) \\ \hline
3 & -12\pi\zeta(3) \\ \hline
4 & 114\pi\zeta(4) \\ \hline
5 & -1177.6529...\cdot\pi\zeta(5) \\ \hline
6 & 14420.2439...\cdot\pi\zeta(6) \\ \hline
7 & -203649.3734...\cdot\pi\zeta(7) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Now the values for $n=2,3,4$ are particularly nice when written in this form, and I managed to calculate those three integrals using dubiously rigorous contour integral methods which are far too unwieldy for anything more. The half-angle substitution leads to various ugly nested sums which I don't know how to evaluate. However (according to WolframAlpha) the patter apparently breaks at $n=5$, even though it was going so well! Does anyone know if/how it is possible to obtain a closed form solution?

Comment: The fifth value is probably not rational https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int((ln(2%2B2*cos(x)))%5E5,%7Bx,0,pi%7D)%2F(pi*Zeta(5))

Comment: $I(n)=\underset{t\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial t^n}\frac{4^t \sqrt{\pi }
   \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+t\right)}{\Gamma (1+t)}$

Comment: Interesting identity! Is the limit necessary? The differentiated function is smooth at 0. Anyway, any tips on how to derive this result?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk [This paper](https://mafiadoc.com/evaluation-of-higher-order-derivatives-of-the-gamma-function_5ba8409d097c4758138b46a9.html) provides a finite procedure for evaluating the derivatives of $\Gamma$ at $1$ and $1/2$ in terms of $\zeta$ and Euler-Mascheroni's $\gamma$. In light of your derivative formula, this also provides a finite procedure for evaluating the integral. This solves the problem as far as I am concerned at least in principle, however due to the large amount of computation involved I'm still interested if there is perhaps a faster approach. Great solution, though!

Comment: If it turns out this is the best we can do, post the derivation as a standalone answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I used CAS and: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471418/integral-int-0-infty-logx2-e-x-mathrmdx?rq=1 thats all.

Comment: Is my answer satisfactory? is there anything I can do to improve it?

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a while and forgot to check this question... I've accepted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to go about this would be by defining 
$$E(s)=\int_0^\pi(2+2\cos x)^sdx$$
Then your integral is given by, from the Leibniz rule, 
$$I_n=E^{(n)}(0)$$
Anyway, we have 
$$E(s)=2^s\int_0^\pi(1+\cos x)^s dx$$
We have the identity $1+\cos x=2\cos^2(x/2)$ so
$$E(s)=4^s\int_0^\pi \cos^{2s}(x/2)dx$$
$t=\frac{x}2$:
$$E(s)=2^{2s-1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2s}(x)dx$$
We have that 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^a(x)\cos^b(x)dx=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{a+1}2)\Gamma(\frac{b+1}2)}{2\Gamma(\frac{a+b}{2}+1)}\qquad \text{Re }a,\text{Re }b>-1$$
Hence
$$E(s)=2^{2s-2}\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(s+1/2)}{\Gamma(s+1)}$$
And $$I_n=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\right)^n2^{2s}\frac{\Gamma(s+1/2)}{\Gamma(s+1)}\Bigg|_{s=0}$$